# Алгоритм перевода номера телефона

Tags: java, android

Сервер принимает ответ вида : +79521134356
Пользователь в EditText можент ввести , как 11 значный номер, так и 12 значный.
Всего 3 типа.

+79521134356 - тогда гуд.

79521134356 - надо добавить +

89521134356 - надо изменить 8 на 7 и приписать +

Как это все реализовать?Помогите написать алгоритм или поделитесь им.

Comment: Если у вас телефонный номер может быть только из России, тогда стоит вывести +7 перед ячейкой, а в саму ячейку позволять вводить только 10 цифр.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatNumber("+79521134356"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("79521134356"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("89521134356"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("+7-952-113-43-56"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("+7 952 113 43 56"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("+7?952.113.43:56"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("+7_LOL_952_LOL_1134356"));
    System.out.println(formatNumber("12345"));
}

private static String formatNumber(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(\\D)*", "");
    int len = s.length();
    if (len >= 10) {
        s = s.substring(len - 10);
        s = "+7" + s;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cлишком короткий номер: " + s);
        s = null;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Вывод:

+79521134356

+79521134356

+79521134356

+79521134356

+79521134356

+79521134356

+79521134356

Cлишком короткий номер: 12345

null

Comment: вместо "+7" можно подставить код любой страны

Comment: Правильнее удалять "все, что не цифры". Скобочки, неразрывные пробелы, длинные тире - и все сломается...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, переделал

Answer (score 5):

Советую использовать данное [решение](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
    mask:mask="+7(###)###-##-##" //решетки можно поменять на любые другие символы
    />
```

Comment: данное решение не позваляет вставлять номер телефона, даже при длинном нажатии.